# poll addition of new object in mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a python script which needs to do some actions whenever a new object is added in a collection
is there any efficient method to poll for addition of new object in mongodb collection?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at mongodb 'tailable' cursor.

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors

Use "find" method of your python driver with "tailable" = true,
it will keep realtime track of additions in the database just like "tail -f" of a file in linux .

Tailable is FALSE by default.
http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html

**find**([spec=None[, fields=None[, skip=0[, limit=0[, timeout=True[, snapshot=False[, **tailable=False**[, sort=None[, max_scan=None[, as_class=None[, slave_okay=False[, **kwargs]]]]]]]]]]]])

**tailable** (optional): the result of this find call will be a tailable cursor - tailable cursors aren’t closed when the last data is retrieved but are kept open and the cursors location marks the final document’s position. if more data is received iteration of the cursor will continue from the last document received. For details, see the tailable cursor documentation.

Comment: Tailable cursors are only permitted on capped collections. If your collection is capped, this will work. If you are using replication, you can use a tailable cursor on the oplog -- look at https://github.com/RedBeard0531/mongo-oplog-watcher/blob/master/mongo_oplog_watcher.py which does so and provides hooks for subclasses to implement. The `ns` field is the namespace in the form `dbname`.`collection_name`, which you can use to filter for the collection you care about.

Comment: I don't have capped collection and not using replication either, how  can i poll in this case. please help

Answer (score 1):

use a separate thread to poll the data. It is less efficient but works..

the alternative solution is to use twisted and its async driver but you still need to poll
the data.